Stack Exchange Moderator Agreement contractual restrictions on activities taken by moderators
I'm a moderator on Worldbuilding Stackexchange, and as such I am bound by the Stackexchange Moderator Agreement
At the moment, Worldbuilding Stackexchange is scheduled to be the subject of a test of advertising on our site, to which all the users who are active on that Meta post so far appear to be opposed.
My question is:  Is there anything in the Stackexchange Moderator Agreement that would prevent a moderator from posting, in Meta and/or elsewhere, instructions or a request for instructions on how users may avoid seeing these unwelcome advertisements?   In other words, could performing such an action or encouraging another person to do so be considered a breach of this contract?

Isn't the way to avoid seeing them "get 200 reputation to unlock the 'see less ads' privilege"?

Why Stack Overflow Doesn’t Care About Ad Blockers
